# How to combine variable value to constant value and output as constant

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I want to pass variable value to a part of constant value to do formatting in excel file using phpspreadsheet.

1) I have defined constant and and call constant value by using variable value.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet as Worksheet;
$value                    ='PORTRAIT';
define("PORTRAIT", Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);              
define("LANDSCAPE",Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$orientation_constantvalue=constant($value);        
$set_orientation          =$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation($orientation_constantvalue);
```

This one worked.

2) I have passed variable value directly to part of constant value.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet as Worksheet;
$value                    ='PORTRAIT';
$orientation_constantvalue="Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_{$value}";
$set_orientation          =$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation($orientation_constantvalue);
```

This one did not work.

If possible, I want to pass variable value directly to constant value, This is because, we may not need to define constant for each type of possible value in constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As done in your first example, you need to fetch the value of the class constant with the `constant` function by passing the name your are calculating dynamically. Meanwhile, with the class alias, you need to hack the call a little bit as proposed in this [4 years old comment in php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php#117145).

Here is the test I made. I don't have your library installed so I created something from scratch as a reusable minimal example.

I first created `class.php` with a namespaced class:

```php
<?php
namespace Toto\Pipo;
class Bingo {
    const ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = "Value for Portrait";
    const ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = "Value for Lanscape";
}
```

I then created a `use_class_constant.php` script doing what you are trying to achieve:

```php
<?php
include('class.php');
use Toto\Pipo\Bingo as Worksheet;

$orientation = 'PORTRAIT';
echo constant(Worksheet::class."::ORIENTATION_{$orientation}") . "\n";
```

And here is the result:

```sh
$ php use_class_constant.php 
Value for Portrait
```

If needed, this is the php version I used:

```sh
$ php -v
PHP 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2019 14:12:38) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Yes, it works nicely.Thank you. But, need to write full reference `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_`.Since, we already defined `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet as Worksheet`.Still could not use **Worksheet** for this purpose

Comment: Edit posted which meets all your requirements (delta a needed call hack in `constant`)

Comment: Yes, It works perfectly.I did this way. `$orientation_constantvalue =constant(Worksheet::class."\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_{$value}") ;`.Thanks for information link,answer and time. I went through content in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that work by passing value to constant and output as constant:

```
$orientation_constantvalue =constant('PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_'.$value);
$set_orientation            =$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation($orientation_constantvalue);
```

For this,

> could not use 'use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet as **Worksheet**;'
>
> and concatenate  **Worksheet**\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_ with $value.

Then, it throw error could not find constant.

We need to write full reference and concatenate with variable in constant

> constant('PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_'.$value);

Then, it works.